# Как обновить UI, пока работает функция в основном потоке

Tags: c#, wpf

Добрый день. У меня есть приложение на WPF. На MainWindow есть canvas, и функция, которая обрабатывает все контролы в нем. Функция работает в главном потоке, иначе не получить объекты с canvas. Я хочу сделать какую-либо визуализацию процесса на этом экране, например изменение textbox. Как это лучше сделать?

```
    public void SomeLongFunk()
    {
         foreach(var item in canvas.Children)
         {
              //dosomething
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы функция, работающая в потоке "достучалась" до UI объектов, нужно использовать анонимные функции:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate () {
textbox.Text = "Almost done!";
});
```

Comment: Обратите внимание: функция работает в **основном** потоке!

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша функция длинная, и работает при этом с UI-объектами, то вы делаете неправильно. Необходимо длительную работу выгружать в другие потоки, чтобы не блокировать главный поток. Для того, чтобы ваш код всё ещё мог взаимодействовать с UI, можно воспользоваться либо `async`/`await`, либо `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`, либо `IProgress`.

Примеры:

`async`/`await`:

```
async Task MoveObjects()
{
    // собираем данные в UI-потоке
    var currentPositions = Arena.Children.Select(child =>
                              new Point(Canvas.GetX(child), Canvas.GetY(child))).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // вычисляем новые данные в новом потоке
        var newPositions =
            await Task.Run(() => engine.ComputeNextPositions(currentPositions));
        // присваиваем данные UI-объектам в UI-потоке
        for (int i = 0; i < Arena.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            var child = Arena.Children[i];
            var coord = newPositions[i];
            Canvas.SetX(child, coord.X);
            Canvas.SetY(child, coord.Y);
        }
        currentPositions = newPositions;
        await Task.Delay(25);
    }
}
```

`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`:

```
Task MoveObjects()
{
    var objects = Arena.Children.ToList();
    return Task.Run(() => MoveObjectsInBackground(objects, Dispatcher));
}

async Task MoveObjectsInBackground(List<UIElement> objects, Dispatcher dispatcher)
{
    // собираем данные в UI-потоке
    var currentPositions =
            await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                objects.Select(child => new Point(Canvas.GetX(child),
                                                  Canvas.GetY(child))).ToList());

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // вычисляем новые данные
        var newPositions = ComputeNewPositions(currentPositions);
        // отправляем их в UI-поток
        await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++)
                {
                    var child = objects[i];
                    var coord = newPositions[i];
                    Canvas.SetX(child, coord.X);
                    Canvas.SetY(child, coord.Y);
                }
            });
        await Task.Delay(25);
    }
}
```

`IProgress`:

```
Task MoveObjects()
{
    // собираем данные в UI-потоке
    var positions = Arena.Children.Select(child =>
                              new Point(Canvas.GetX(child), Canvas.GetY(child))).ToList();
    var progress = new Progress<List<Point>>(UpdatePositions);
    await Task.Run(() => MoveObjectsInBackground(positions, progress);
}

void UpdatePositions(List<Point> positions)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Arena.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        var child = Arena.Children[i];
        var coord = newPositions[i];
        Canvas.SetX(child, coord.X);
        Canvas.SetY(child, coord.Y);
    }
}

void MoveObjectsInBackground(List<Point> positions, IProgress<List<Point>> progress)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var newPositions = ComputeNewPositions(currentPositions);
        progress.Report(newPositions);
        currentPositions = newPositions;
        Thread.Sleep(25);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Функция работает в главном потоке, **иначе не получить объекты с canvas**"* - да что за день такой?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Предложение в том и состоит, чтобы выгрузить функцию в фоновый поток. Длинной функции нечего делать в UI-потоке.